# shared objects factory - updating weak_ptr map

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a scenario where many objects may need to load some resource but when a path to the resource is the same a resource object should be shared. The following simplified code presents the above concept:

```
struct Obj
{
};

struct SharedObjects
{
    std::shared_ptr<Obj> CreateObj(const std::string& key)
    {
        auto itr = registry_.find(key);
        if(itr != registry_.end())
        {
            return itr->second.lock();
        }
        auto obj = std::make_shared<Obj>();
        registry_[key] = obj;
        return obj;
    }

    void ObjRemoved(const std::string& key)
    {
        auto itr = registry_.find(key);
        if(itr != registry_.end())
        {
            if(!itr->second.use_count())
            {
                registry_.erase(itr);
            }
        }
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::weak_ptr<Obj>> registry_;
};

int main()
{
    SharedObjects sharedObjects;
    auto p1 = sharedObjects.CreateObj("a");
    auto p2 = sharedObjects.CreateObj("b");
    auto p3 = sharedObjects.CreateObj("a");

    p2.reset();
    sharedObjects.ObjRemoved("b");
}
```

I wonder how I can improve updating weak_ptr map ? As you can see now I call reset and ObjRemoved functions. Do you have any ideas ? (Maybe I should use some design pattern). Do you see any other places in the code which can be improved ?

**Edit1**
Here is possible solution:

empty weak_ptr can be removed from the Obj dtor:

```
struct Obj
{
    Obj::Obj(std::function<void()> clb): clb_(std::move(clb))
    {}
    Obj::~Obj()
    {
        clb_();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> clb_;
};
```

Modified CreateObj function(ObjRemoved function is removed):

```
std::shared_ptr<Obj> SharedObjects::CreateObj(const std::string& key)
{
    auto itr = registry_.find(key);

    if(itr != registry_.end())
    {
        return itr->second.lock();
    }

   auto obj = std::make_shared<Obj>([this, key]
   {
       registry_.erase(key);
   });

   registry_[key] = obj;
   return obj;
}
```

**Edit2**
Alternative solution without smart pointers:

```
struct Obj
{
};

struct SharedObj
{
    Obj* CreateObj(const std::string& key)
    {
        auto itr = registry.find(key);
        if(itr != registry.end())
        {
            ++(itr->second.refCount);
            return &itr->second.obj;
        }

        auto& objRecord = registry[key] = ObjRecord{};
        return &objRecord.obj;
    }

    void RemoveObj(const std::string& key)
    {
        auto itr = registry.find(key);
        if (itr != registry.end())
        {
            auto& refCount = itr->second.refCount;
            --refCount;

            if (refCount == 0)
            {
                registry.erase(itr);
            }
        }
    }
private:
    struct ObjRecord
    {
        Obj obj;
        std::uint16_t refCount{1};
    };
    std::unordered_map<std::string, ObjRecord> registry;
};
```

Comment: The shown approach seems to be fundamentally flawed. If a discrete function is required to "ObjRemove" an object that's no longer to be used, then storing the objects in weak pointers serves absolutely no useful purpose whatsoever. Furthermore, the whole reason for using smart pointers is to eliminate the need to formally remove/destroy objects. The smart pointers will do that for you. You need to rethink your entire approach.

Comment: From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr): "`std::weak_ptr` is a smart pointer that holds a **non-owning** ("weak") reference to an object that is managed by `std::shared_ptr`." When `p2` is reset, the pointer is already invalid... I don't think `std::weak_prt` is used a lot (anymore). This might be an XY problem: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let's imagine that a program works a long time and some shared objects are destroyed but map which keeps weak_ptr grows infinitely. I should remove empty weak ptrs from the map.

Comment: Just loop through the map and remove all expired `weak_ptr`s once every 2 minutes of whatever is suitable.

Comment: Please see Edit1, what do you think ?

Comment: Your edited solution:  the lambda captured by `std::function` now contains a raw pointer to `SharedObjects`.  UB results if the `SharedObjects` is deleted before any of the objects created by it - which is pretty hard to ensure given that you hand off `shared_ptr`s to the caller of `CreateObj()` and it is whatever it does that keeps the objects around.    You also violate the singe-responsibility principle here - you might be better splitting the factory and registry.

Comment: As for your original question: In effect what you have here is a cache for sharing objects.   Once ownership of the created object reaches `0` it gets deleted, but the cache-key remains in the map, mapping to a nullified `std::weak_ptr()`.  You leak a map entry.    Probably not big deal unless the map has many keys.  If it really bothers you, occasionally walk the map and delete keys that no longer map to active objects. 
BTW: This is a pretty common pattern when implementing the observer pattern and you allow multiple registrations for a key.

Comment: Incidentally: this is one of the few places you should *not* use `std::make_shared<T>()`: As an optimisation it allocates the object and extrinsic control block together in the same heap block; it can only be released when the last weak reference goes away - which is never in your original code.   Instead prefer `auto obj = std::shared_ptr<Obj>{new Obj{}};`

Comment: Isn't a simple `std::unordered_map<std::string, Obj>` enough?

Comment: L. F. there have to be some reference counting. Please see Edit2 for an alternative solution. Do you think it will be more efficient ?